# Filepicker.io - upload via URL and cURL

Tags: curl, filepicker.io

It it possible to do the following?

1. upload an image to Filepicker.io by giving it a URL
2. do it via cURL

I can't find in the documentation where it mentions either of these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible:

```
>>> curl -X POST -F fileUpload=@filename.txt https://www.filepicker.io/api/store/S3?key=MY_API_KEY
{"url": "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/WmFxB2aSe20SGT2kzSsr", "size": 234, "type": "text/plain", "filename": "tester.txt", "key": "1ilWxmaRRqhMd2vSbSyB_tester.txt"}
```

or

```
>>> curl -X POST -d url="https://www.filepicker.io/static/img/watermark.png" https://www.filepicker.io/api/store/S3?key=MY_API_KEY
{"url": "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/N49i6hPRBeropWnCWOLw", "size": 8331, "type": "image/png", "filename": "watermark.png", "key": "a1RyBxiglW92bS2SRmqM_watermark.png"}
```

Full documentation at https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#fpurl-store

Comment: True, but it helps clarify what's going on when provided in documentation, particularly when people are translating from a curl request to another language/library

Comment: I disagree. I find that most users actually get mislead by the -X as it leads them into believing that -X controls something it doesn't. Like you can see other examples on that page that really doesn't use -X in a sensible way...